# c# Execute command line and return string

Tags: c#, command-line, command-prompt

I can't get this to return anything, I'm expecting a list of files in the current directory but it's returning nothing.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PublishProject();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void PublishProject()
    {
        //Create process
        var pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process
        {
            StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "dir",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = "C:\\"
                }
        };
        pProcess.Start();
        Console.Write(pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        pProcess.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using System.IO classes?

Answer (score 8):

You can make this work by changing `Arguments` to:

```
Arguments = "/C dir",
```

The [/C Flag](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) "Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.".  Without this, *cmd* is still executing, which is why you get no output immediately.

That being said, for this example, I would personally use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) or [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) instead of a process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list down the files in the directory, the best way is to use the `Directory` class from `System.IO` as follows:

```
using System.IO;

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\");

// loop to display the filenames
for (int i=0; i < files.Length(); i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
}
```

*note that this is not a full working source code because it doesn't contain the `main()` function.